# Algorithm used to calculate hashcode for segments in ConcurrentHashMap in Java

Tags: concurrenthashmap

What is the Algorithm used to calculate hashcode for segments in Concurrent HashMap in Java ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly we know that Concurrent HashMap is divided into a finite number of segments.

Segment is a final class inside Concurrent HashMap .

```
         The definition of Segment is as below:

          /** Inner Segment class plays a significant role **/
               protected static final class Segment {
               protected int count;
              protected synchronized int getCount() {
               return this.count;
                }
                protected synchronized void synch() {}
                   }
                /** Segment Array declaration **/
             public final Segment[] segments = new Segment[32];//By default 
              // i am taking as 32.
```

Let me explain by taking put method of ConcurrentHashMap class.

```
                put(Object key, Object value)
```

Before placing this map into anyone one of those 32 segments we need to 
calculate the hashcode right.

First we calculate the hash of key:

```
                int hashVal = hash(key);
               static int hash(Object x) {
                int h = x.hashCode();
                return (h << 7) - h + (h >>> 9) + (h >>> 17);
                 }
```

After getting the hashVal we can decide the Segment as below:

```
                     Segment seg = segments[(hash & 0x1F)];     
              // segments is an array defined above
```

This is just for understanding refer oracle docs for their practices.